# Calculus minimizing problem

Tags: calculus

> Consider the implicitly defined function $y = f(x)$ which satisfies
>   the form  $(x,y) = (2e^t -e^{-t}, 2e^t + e^{-t})$, find the minimum of
>   $y$.

Can I just work with $y(x(t)) = 2e^t + e^{-t}$ and find the minimum with respect to $t$? (Setting $\frac{d}{dt} y(x(t)) = 0$ and so on)

Am I missing something?
I don't think I need to use Lagrange multiplier or any differential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it, but it is $y(t)=2e^t+e^{-t}$, not $y(x(t))$  Find the $t$ that minimizes this, then plug that $t$ into the expression for $x$ and you are done.